# Lectura de cookie situada en otro directorio

Tags: php, cookies

Buenas tengo un problema con un ejercicio a la hora de visualizar las cookies creadas.

Tengo el siguiente arbol de directorios:
- / (el directorio por default donde tengos los php)
- /nivel
- /nivel/nivel2

Entonces el problema es que si creo una cookie poniendole como path /nivel1 o /nivel1/nivel2 no soy capaz de visualizar estas cookies, pero si puedo visualizar las que tienen de path "/"

El código con el que creo la cookie:

```
if (isset($_POST['envio'])) { 
    $nombre     = sanearDato($_POST['nombre']);
    $contenido  = sanearDato($_POST['contenido']);
    $nivel      = sanearDato($_POST['nivel']);

    if (empty($nombre))     $nombre     = "NONE";
    if (empty($contenido))  $contenido  = "NONE";

    switch($nivel) {
        case "0": $nivel = "/"; break;
        case "1": $nivel = "/nivel1"; break;
        case "2": $nivel = "/nivel1/nivel2"; break;
    }

    setcookie($nombre, $contenido."_".$nivel, time()+60*60, $nivel);
}
```

Cuando visualizo el $_COOKIE con var_dump no me muestra ninguna cookie a la que le he dado un path diferente a "/", pero si los que lo tienen.

¿Hay alguna forma de poder visualizar esas cookies que tienen el path /nivel1 o /nivel1/nivel2 ?

Un  saludo.

Comment: No me queda claro la parte de crear la cookie con la path, si puedieras decirme cómo creas las cookies podría mirarte algo.

Comment: Hola buenas, acabo de actualizar el post, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

El problema que estás teniendo es por los `path` que añades. Cuando creas una `cookie` con una `path`, este será visible cuando estes en esa ruta o en alguna ruta inferior a esta.

Es decir, si creas una cookie con la path `"/"`, esa ruta y las de abajo podrán ver la cookie. Si la creas en `"/nivel1"`, la cookie se puede ver en `"/nivel1"` y `"/nivel1/nivel2"` pero no en la raiz. Por último si la creas en `"/nivel1/nivel2"`, está solo se verá en esa ruta.

Para poder crear una tabla con todas las cookies la deberías de hacer desde el elemento más lejano a la raiz, ya que desde aquí todas las cookies son accesibles.

Comment: Hola compañero, gracias por tu respuesta, algo así he pensado, mover los scripts al nivel2 y así con la herencia podría hacer un visualizado de todas las cookies, ya que no veo otra forma posible, a no ser que aloje un script en cada carpeta (nivel 1 y 2) y desde la raiz" los vaya llamando y leyendo, tengo que probarlo, gracias compi!

Comment: Bien, si encuentro algo más ya te comentaré